# how to get anchor tag by class name and autoclick on that using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i get class name of anchor tag and autoclick here's the code

```
<div id="testing">
<a class="download_now link_btn" href="#">Download Now<i></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.download_now link_btn').click()`

Comment: If you want to invoke the natural click of it, then you can use `$('.download_now link_btn')[0].click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the classname:

```
$('#testing a').attr('class');
```

To trigger click:

```
$('#testing a').click();//or $('#testing a').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
var anchor_class=$('#testing a').attr('class'); //get class name
$('.'+anchor_class).click();   // trigger autoclick
```

Answer (score -1):

To display the class name as alert

```
$('.download_now').click(function(){

  alert($(this).attr('class'));

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you want to click anchor(class = download_now) inside div with id = testing

```
$("#testing a.download_now").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
        alert(this.href);
        alert('a');
    });

            OR

$("#testing a.download_now.link_btn").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
        alert(this.href);
        alert('a');
    });
```

If you just want to click anchor any where in the page with class =  download_now

```
$("#testing a.download_now").click(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
         alert(this.href);
        alert('a');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to get anchor tag using class name and auto click.

***Code:***

```
//on load of the page auto click the anchor tag
$(document).ready(function(){   
window.location = $('.download_now').attr('href');  
});
```

Hope this helps.